# Many-To-Many and Where Clause

Tags: c#, linq, many-to-many, where-clause

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Users` and `Divisions`.  I need to be able to get the users based off their divisionId.

I want to write a linq query that would be translated to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE divisionId IN (1, 7)
```

The linq I tried looks like:

```
var users = context.Users.Where(u =>
    u.Divisions.Any(d =>
        divisionIds.Contains(d.DivisionId)));
```

In the above linq, `u.Divisions` is type `List<Division>` and `divisionIds` is of type array (`int[] divisionIds = new int[] { 1, 7 }`) (the divisionIds array is dynamic, it won't always be 1 and 7.  This is just an example).

This requires the user to be in both DivisionId 1 `AND` 7 (I want `OR`).  Any suggestions on what I should do?

### Update

This has been solved.  My code above works, there was another issue.

Comment: LINQ to SQL or Entity Framework?

Comment: `This requires the user to be in both DivisionId 1 AND 7` No it doesn't.  It already has the semantics you want.  If any of the divisions match any of the values, the row is returned, which is what you say you want.

Comment: Maybe there is another issue then that I'll look into, but right only only users who have both divisionIds are appearing.